# conda pip msgpack-python installed twice with different versions - select one or the other

Tags: python, pip, conda, spacy, msgpack

I installed

```
conda install msgpack-python
```

and tries to do

```
pip install -Iv msgpack-python==0.5.4
```

but it didn´t work -> Successfully installed msgpack-python-0.5.6; Cleaning up...

So I removed the conda pkg and installed with pip again, so that version 0.5.4 is available.

But If I need both versions for different usage, is there a way so select the one pkg 0.5.6 or the version 0.5.4 when both versions are installed (one via pip and the other via conda)?

**Added**:
It is possible to have both versions in different versions (on via pip and one via conda):

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/8b/b8/3ab1585ec7ac02afff2427d5727b922d2907466edd932d98002f0a18c29a/msgpack-python-0.5.4.tar.gz#md5=6abd8cca9caa61c7dcb9b9214f9e600f
pip show msgpack-python
pip install hunspell spacy_hunspell
conda install -y spacy
conda list msgpack
```

Comment: Yes, use two different environments. You cannot install both versions to one version of Python

Comment: it´s in (Ana)conda

Comment: You need to create separate environments for the two versions. It is not easy/nearly impossible to have both available to a single Python at the same time